# MVC5 Create View with Dropdowns fails when validation is not successful

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have an MVC5 view to allow users to create objects. The Create view i produce for a new get request is bound to a strongly typed model. That model contains SelectListItems that i populate so the user has some lists to choose from. User makes some selections mashes save and it comes back to the post action in my controller and saves the record all well and good.
However, if there are validation errors - like an empty field - i want to handle that in my post Create ActionResult. So i wrote a validator and i check everything out and i load up error messages in my model state. 
Then i call:

```
return View (m)
```

which i want to return the same view with the model in it so the user sees what they have typed already and the errors are shown in a summary section and they can fix those and move on.
The issue is that the page breaks because there are no items in the SelectListItems that i had previously filled in. I can see when the post ActionResult is called that my model, m, has all of the values i need in it to create the new record but the SelectLists are null.

How can show the page back to the user with the errors?

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CreateNewProjectModel m, UserInfoCookie userCookie, string redirect, string submitButton)
    {
        var mValidateResults = ProjectDetailsValidator.Validate(m);
        if (!mValidateResults.IsValid)
        {
            //loop over each error
            foreach (var e in mValidateResults.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(e.PropertyName, e.ErrorMessage);
            }
            return View(m);}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, **HTTP is stateless**. In your code you are returning the view again. But you are not **(re)loading** the properties which is being used to populate the dropdown content.

So before returning the data, you need to populate your data for the dropdown again.

```
//Validation failed, Let's reload data and return to the view
// Hard coded for demo. you may get it from db
m.States = new List<SelectListItem> { 
  new SelectListItem { Value="1", Text="Michigan"},
  new SelectListItem { Value="2", Text="Texas"}
};
return View(m);
```

Assuming your `CreateNewProjectModel` view model has a `States` property of type `List<SelectListItem>` and you use that to render your dropdown.

```
@model YourViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm)
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.FirstName)
  @Html.DropDownListFor(s=>s.SelectedState,Model.States)
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

Comment: that makes sense. but why are these lists not sent IN with the post in the first place?

Comment: That is by design. It sends back form field's value (selected value of your dropdown), not the data used to build the dropdown. In web forms, they used to keep that in view state and it will be a part of the post to persist it between 2 calls. In MVC, No view state concept : ) Clean. You need to reload it. MVC reminds us every time HTTP is stateless which we forgot with stupid web forms :)